# Casperjs: Open a new window/tab

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, slimerjs

I am trying to create a test script that will go through my site, click on a link and open a new tab to another website, fill out a form submit it and then go back to original website, however every example I have looked at and tried does not work for me.  The page runs until there it opens the new window and then the new window sits there for about 5 seconds and everything closes.  Here is what I got:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1920, height: 1075};
casper.on('page.error', function(msg, trace) {
   this.echo('Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR');
   for(var i=0; i<trace.length; i++) {
       var step = trace[i];
       this.echo('   ' + step.file + ' (line ' + step.line + ')', 'ERROR');
   }
});

casper.test.begin('Resurrectio test', function(test) {
   casper.start('https://mywebsite1/abc/default.asp');
   casper.waitForSelector("form[name=FormSize] input[name='a']",
       function success() {
           test.assertExists("form[name=FormSize] input[name='Nickname']");
           this.click("form[name=FormSize] input[name='Account']");
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("form[name=FormSize] input[name='Nickname']");
   });
   casper.waitForSelector("input[name='Nickname']",
       function success() {
           this.sendKeys("input[name='Nickname']", "abcco40");
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("input[name='Nickname']");
   });
   casper.waitForSelector("form[name=FormSize] input[name='Username']",
       function success() {
           test.assertExists("form[name=FormSize] input[name='Username']");
           this.click("form[name=FormSize] input[name='Username']");
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("form[name=FormSize] input[name='Username']");
   });
   casper.waitForSelector("input[name='Username']",
       function success() {
           this.sendKeys("input[name='Username']", "k_csr");
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("input[name='Username']");
   });
   casper.waitForSelector("form[name=FormSize] input[name='Password']",
       function success() {
           test.assertExists("form[name=FormSize] input[name='Password']");
           this.click("form[name=FormSize] input[name='Password']");
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("form[name=FormSize] input[name='Password']");
   });
   casper.waitForSelector("input[name='Password']",
       function success() {
           this.sendKeys("input[name='Password']", "kcsr");
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("input[name='Password']");
   });
   casper.waitForSelector("form[name=FormSize] input[type=submit][value='Logon']",
       function success() {
           test.assertExists("form[name=FormSize] input[type=submit][value='Logon']");
           this.click("form[name=FormSize] input[type=submit][value='Logon']");
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("form[name=FormSize] input[type=submit][value='Logon']");
   });
   /* submit form */
   casper.waitForSelector(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='One Time Payment']"),
       function success() {
           test.assertExists(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='One Time Payment']"));
           this.click(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='One Time Payment']"));
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='One Time Payment']"));
   });
   casper.waitForPopup(/https:\/\/secondwebsite\/home\/three\.aspx/).withPopup(/https:\/\/secondwebsite\/home\/three\.aspx/, function(){
        popup.close();
   });

   casper.then(function() {
    });

   /* submit form */
   casper.waitForSelector("form#aspnetForm input[type=button][value='Back']",
       function success() {
           test.assertExists("form#aspnetForm input[type=button][value='Back']");
           this.click("form#aspnetForm input[type=button][value='Back']");
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("form#aspnetForm input[type=button][value='Back']");
   });
   casper.waitForSelector(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='Document Manager']"),
       function success() {
           test.assertExists(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='Document Manager']"));
           this.click(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='Document Manager']"));
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='Document Manager']"));
   });

   casper.run(function() {test.done();});
});
```

Comment: What PhantomJS/slimerJS version are you using? Where is `popup` defined?

Comment: phantom is 1.9.8
slimer is 0.9.6

Forgot to remove popup, if I try any other command it just ignores it, the window hangs till it crashes.  It doesn't even activate the following steps.

Comment: You can see that the syntax highlighting has problems with the window URLs. Have you tried with proper regular expressions? `/https:\/\/secondwebsite\.tld\/home\/three\.aspx/` If this doesn't help Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I upated it to have proper regex so it matches what you have shown me, however the results are the same as before.  What do you mean by register to the events?

Comment: There is an examples link in my  previous comment.

Comment: I added the extra logging for casper however it produced nothing

Comment: I got it to work.  thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer how I got it to work.  Thank you for your help, you cleared a few things for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to remove the following code from the main flow and move it inside withPopup function.  Also the argument passed in withPopup and waitForPopUp needs to have regex expressions not links, something I did not fully understand before.  When passing those argument you do not need to encapsulate them in quotes, this part I don't fully understand why but it wants the argument as a pure regex expression without the quotes.

```
casper.waitForSelector("form#aspnetForm input[type=button][value='Back']",
       function success() {
           test.assertExists("form#aspnetForm input[type=button][value='Back']");
           this.click("form#aspnetForm input[type=button][value='Back']");
       },
       function fail() {
           test.assertExists("form#aspnetForm input[type=button][value='Back']");
   });
```